# concatenation fails to add null field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use the below query

```
select TOP 1 Number,ltrim(rtrim(first_field)) + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim( second_field)) as FirstName, 
            from  ViewName _details with(nolock) 
            where _details.ID=2912
```

Here `second_field` is null hence `FirstName` column is returning as null

Comment: Use `COALESCE` to avoid the null values as set default value if null  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF;
```

Read more here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Use `COALESCE` to avoid the null values as set default value if null. [you can find more about it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx).You can use coalesce to get first not null value. So if your any other column contains the not null value you might want to use in case of `null` then you can use that column name as your second column and so on.

```
       select TOP 1   
              Number,
              ltrim(rtrim(COALESCE(first_field,anyothercolumnwithvalue,'yourdefaultvalue'))) + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(COALESCE(second_field,anyothercolumnwithvalue,'yourdefaultvalue'))) as FirstName, 
        from  
              ViewName _details with(nolock) 
        where 
              _details.ID=2912
```

Comment: Thanks
will COALESCE generate null if its having expression involving non-null parameter?
any difference or advantage of using COALESCE against isnull?

Comment: `COALESCE(col1,col2,col3,....,'defaultvalue')`  as you can see the syntax it merely checks for the col1 if its null it will move on to the col2 if null move on to col3 till it finds the not null value. So it is good if there are condition when you are not sure if the column is null or not  and if null then you want to use another col value or default value.[You can read it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `coalesce` to deal with nulls

```
coalesce(field, 'text to replace null')
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `,` after `FirstName` and use [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) for both fields

```
select TOP 1 Number,ltrim(rtrim(ISNULL(first_field,''))) + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim( ISNULL(second_field,''))) as FirstName from  ViewName _details with(nolock) 
            where _details.ID=2912
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example of basic usage of *ISNULL* function

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULL,'REPLACED-NULL'); --Returns REPLACED-NULL

SELECT ISNULL('Original Value','Replace-Original-With-Me-If-NULL'); --Returns Original Value
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/23849)